# Unable to login heroku

Tags: heroku

I was using GIT BASH to connect with the Heroku server, I have successfully logged into the heroku website and downloaded Heroku Toolbelt 3.2.0 for windows. When i tried to log in using the GIT Bash it throws me the error message.

> Error:       A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host. - connect(2) (Errno::EHOSTUNREACH) (Excon::Errors::Socket

I tried to update the proxy setting using,

```
set HTTP_PROXY=:http//%username%:%password%@%SERVER%:%PORT%
```

and using

```
export HTTP_PROXY='http://user:pass@proxy:port'
```

After setting this proxy when i tried to log in it throws an error message saying,

> Error:       getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (SocketError) (Excon::Errors::SocketError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried using the export command with the following parameters the issue gets resolved.
The export command were:

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://SERVER:PORT"
```

and

```
export HTTPS_PROXY="https://SERVER:PORT"
```

Comment: Check [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#using-an-http-proxy) out for windows users too.

Answer (score 0):

`git bash` doesn't seem like a valid command. Are you trying to connect to the Heroku dyno to play around with the environment? If so, you should try: `heroku run bash`.